# Expand Image To Show Text

Tags: html

I'm extremely new to coding. I'm coding a page and I want to have 3 images in one row and each image drops down text/links/information once clicked, and when clicked again it hides it.

Either that or too have an image to the right of the page and it expands text to the right of the image in a cool effect, however the effect isn't mandatory to me as I know that involves other code than just normal HTML/CSS etc.

Here is my current code. It has two images one to the right, one to the left. However, the text when expanded appears in between the images.. for both of them.::

```
<a href="javascript: hideshow('zznam')"><img src="imgurl" border="0" align="left"/></a>
<div id="zznam">Text 1 Here!</div>

<a href="javascript: hideshow('zz1')"><img src="imgurl" border="0" align="right"/></a>
<div id="zz1" style="display: none;">Text 1 Here!</div>
```

with the script in the header.

Could you please help me out?

```
<script type="text/Javascript">
<!--
function hideshow(id)
{
if(document.getElementById(id).style.display==""){
document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
} else {
document.getElementById(id).style.display="";
}
}
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Post your JavaScript also.

Comment: It might be because the `width` property is not enough to expand to the right side of the second image...

Comment: Oops. I should have included that in the first idea I want it to expand the text below the image. I'd resize the images to a small size if I wanted text to expand to the right. Just after the easy option before I do the harder thing.

Comment: Added the JS to the OP.

Comment: Bumping this as still can't find an answer.